# Morphisms of flat families of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

$X$: projective scheme over a scheme $S$.

$E, F$: $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules, flat/$S$

$\phi$: $E \rightarrow F$ : morphism s.t. $\phi_t$: $E_t \rightarrow F_t$ is zero morphism for all $t \in S$

Then, is $\phi$ zero morphism ?

I'd be glad if you could tell me something!
(Please give me some comments about the comment below!)

Edit: especially I am interested in the case $X = Y \times S$ ,where $Y$: projective surface / $\mathbb{C}$, $S: \mathbb{C}$-scheme

Answer (score 4):

No. For instance, take 
$$
X = S = \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2),
\qquad 
E = F = \Bbbk[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2,
\qquad 
\phi  = \epsilon.
$$
Then for the unique point $t \in S$ the morphism $\phi_t$ is zero, while $\phi$ is not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If$Y, S$: $\mathbb{C}$-schemes and $Y$: projective over $\mathbb{C}$ of dim $>0$ and $X := Y \times S$,then is the question true ?

Comment: @Walter field: I think you can cross the above example by P1. Let everything be over $\mathbb C$, $D:=Spec(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$, $X:=D\times\mathbb{P}^1$, $\pi:X\to D$, $E:=I$ where $I=\pi^{*}(\epsilon)$, $F:=\mathcal O_X$, and $E\to F$ the inclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But, how do we prove $E$ is flat over $D$ ?